# Determining reduced Groebner basis of $I(V)$ by using Lagrange

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier, groebner-basis, groebner-generators

I am working on the following task from Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms by Cox, Little, Shea:

[image]

I already completed parts a and b of the task. But I struggle finishing part c: Using the hint I take $g\in I(V)$. So $g\in K[x,y]$ and $g(a_s,b_s)=0$ $\forall 1\leq s \leq n$. So I thought because of the unambiguity of $h$ that $g$ has to be some kind of $y-h(x)$. But I am not quite sure if this is true. Especially, since $I(V)$ contains the product of $(x-a_i)$ in its generators. I'm happy about any hint!

PS: Since I am new here I would appreciate feedback on the formulation of my entry!

EDIT:
Since $g(a_s,b_s)=0$ and $h$ is the unique polynomial it follows that $g(x,y)=p(x,y)*(y-h(x))$ with $p$ polynomial. Then $g(a_s,b_s)=p(a_s,b_s)*(b_s-h(a_s))=p(a_s,b_s)*0=0$. But I do not understand why $p$ has to be some kind of $(x-a_i)$...

Comment: The formulation of your question is correct. Unfortunately, I am not expert in the domain of algebraic geometry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing $g \in I(V)$ by $\{f(x),y-h(x)\}$, we get
\begin{equation}\tag{$*$}
g = q_1f+q_2(y-h)+r,
\end{equation}
where none of the terms in $r$ are divisible by the leading terms of $f(x)$ and $y-h(x)$, namely $x^n$ and $y$. This means that $r$ is a polynomial only depending on $x$ of degree $\leq n-1$. Moreover, evaluating $(*)$ at $(a_i,b_i)$ yields
\begin{equation}
0 = g(a_i,b_i) = q_1(a_i,b_i)\underbrace{f(a_i)}_{=0}+q_2(a_i,b_i)\underbrace{(b_i-h(a_i))}_{=0}+r(a_i) = r(a_i).
\end{equation}
In other words, $r(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$ vanishing at $n$ distinct points, so it has to be $0$. Therefore, we conclude that $g \in \langle f(x),y-h(x) \rangle$.